# Truncated warning or error massages

Tags: r, model, output

When I try to build a model using PKSFC, I get this message:

[... truncated]

R lists three mistakes and a half (the equations end with *_EC).

I guess I can correct the mistake, but I would like to correct them all in one pass.

I guess there are many more (maybe 15?).

The full message:

> 5: In sfc.check(vn_mod, fill = FALSE) : Equations 
>    57192.4187750356 + POPAGE_1 * (0.5 * (0 - 55335.9694996733)/POPAGE_1 + 0.2 * (POPAGE - POPAGE_1)/POPAGE_1 - 0.2 * (57192.4187750356 - 0.5 * 55335.9694996733 - 0.508679781654891 * POPAGE_1)/POPAGE_1 + ACPOP_EC)
>    28.7269160437129 * exp(0.548725 * log(0/1.489181) + 0.704327 * log(0/37.4835480991331) - 0.247704 *
>   (log(28.7269160437129/37.4835480991331 * (1 + R_SCP_1)) - 0.5 *
>   log(1.489181) - (1 - 0.5) * log(1.52438302758911)) - 0.5 * 0 -
>   0.0511046682618056 + WP_EC)
>    1.25809781599844 * exp(0.2 * log(0/1.46079630578026) + 0.8 * log(PPX * 0/(PPX_1 * 1.1362002193817)) - 0.2 * (log(1.25809781599844) - 0.2 * log(1.46079630578026) - (1 - 0.2) * log(PPX_1 * 1.1362002193817)) -
>   0.00325177611673638 * (T - 2016) * (T <= 2016) - 0.0576138445722962 + PM_EC)
>    1.30468806319261 * exp(0.7 * log(0/1.46079630578026) + 0.3 * log(PPX * 0/(PPX_1 * 1.1362002193817)) - 0.2 * (log(1.30468806319261) - 0.7 * log(1.46079630578026) - (1 - 0.7) * log(PPX_1 * 1.1362002193817)) -
>   0.0033333860060119 * (T - 201 [... truncated]